# What is the best ruby on rails login and authentication plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

the restful authentication plugin does appear to be broken with rails (2.3.4) [name error and yes I know about the bug that is on hold]. Is their a better plugin/gem?

Answer (score 14):

I think most of developers will agree right now, [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is the best authentication plugin.

For authorization, I do personnaly really like [acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9) which perfectly integrates with authlogic.

Comment: Ditto, acl9 looks great. I'll be integrating that for my next project update. Literally uses the same methods I've developed internally. I thought I was so clever ;)

Answer (score 6):

A fairly new entry in this area is [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) which is based on [warden](http://github.com/hassox/warden/), a rack-based authentication solution.

You can see the popularity of the various plugins [over at ruby toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html).

Comment: devise was beyond easy to get a basic implementation going (half an hour or less)... I second this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you look at http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic - It doesn't do the authorization part, but that's never terribly difficult to setup. What it does do, and do well is authentication.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't really give much in the way of criteria so I'm just going to toss this out there.

[authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) and read the associated [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhy no one even mentioned [clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance). Is it really not worth mentioning?

I recently thought about using clearance instead of authlogic in a project, but didn't see enough advantages.